# Dont call hover events on disabled elements

Tags: jquery, html

is there some way to call hover events on disabled html elements? I found solution with wrapping div, but it doesnt work very well.

Forexample:

```
<input type="text" id="someidtext" value="somevalue" disabled="disabled" />
<select id="someidselect" disabled="disabled" > 

$("#someidtext").mouseenter(function () {});
$("#someidselect").mouseenter(function () {});
```

Thanks

Comment: why don't you check the condition inside the handler

Comment: another solution is to use a wrapping element and use event delegation.. `<div id="someidtext_wrapper"><input type="text" id="someidtext" value="somevalue" disabled="disabled" /></div>`... then `$('#someidtext_wrapper').on('mouseenter', 'input:not(:disabled)', function(){
    console.log('x')
});` - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vUw2y/1/

Comment: I didnt find solution. So I thing the best is fire event on not disabled elements. The behaviour of wrapping divs with hover events are not the same like on elements without disabled attributs. Sorry my english.

Answer (score 4):

I think the best solution is to check the condition within the handler.

```
$('#someidtext').mouseenter(function (event) {
    if(!this.disabled){
        console.log('x')
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/asv9R/)

If that is not possible, you may have to think about event delegation based handlers like

```
<div id="someidtext_wrapper">
    <input type="text" id="someidtext" value="somevalue" disabled="disabled" />
</div>
```

then

```
$('#someidtext_wrapper').on('mouseenter', 'input:not(:disabled)', function () {
    console.log('x')
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vUw2y/)

Note: These solutions are based on the assumption that the disables state changes dynamically after the event handlers are registered

Answer (score 0):

See ids should be unique so if you have class names then you can do this:

```
$(".someidtext:not(:disabled)").mouseenter(function (e) {
     console.log(e.type);
});
```

or more global:

```
$(":input:not(:disabled)").mouseenter(function (e) {
     console.log(e.type);
});
```

[Demo with `:input`](http://jsfiddle.net/L2C5G/)

---

`:input` is the selector which selects all input elements whether that element is select, text, submit, button, textarea etc.

Comment: @Alex what is **dynamic** in the question?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions at least. First, add a condition inside the handler function like so:

```
$("#someidtext").mouseenter(function () {
    if (!$(this).attr('disabled')) {
        // the function code
    }
});
```

Secondly, you can bind event using delegation to inputs which are not disabled in the first place:

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", "#someidtext:not(:disabled)", function () {
    // the function code
});
```